# [Maginal distribution Calculation]problem: confusion about the Region of integration

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am confused about the marginal distribution of the joint probabilty function $f(x,y)$.

**Problem:** the joint probabilty function $f(x,y)$ is $1/2$  when $x$ and $y$ are within a rotated square about the origin (its vertex are $(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0), (-1,0)$).  Then it asks to compute the marginal disbribution $f_X(x)$.

Accoding to wiki:

$$p_X(x) = \int_yp_{X,Y}(x,y) dy =  \int_yp_{X|Y}(x|y)p_Y(y) dy
$$

The  valid $x$, $y$ are within this region

[image]

I was having trouble to determine the region that I need to integrate. In this case, as you can see, they are defined as a function of $x$.

**My attempt:**
$$
\int_{y=-x-1}^{x+1} \frac 12 dy
+
\int_{y=x-1}^{-x+1} \frac 12 dy$$

But the answer doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Strange, the density should not be $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain $D$ may be defined by the inequality $$|x|+|y|\leqslant1.$$
The length of a side of the square $D$ is $\sqrt2$ hence its area is $2$ and $(X,Y)$ has density
$$
\frac{\mathbf 1_D}2.
$$
Integrating this (without involving *any* conditional density) yields the density $f_X$ of $X$ as
$$
f_X(x)=(1-|x|)^+.
$$